# How to generate DDL of an object which a synonym points to?

Tags: oracle

I want to generate the DDL of an object which a synonym points to. Consider the below example.

I have a synonym named USER which points to USER_1 table. I want to generate DDL of the USER_1 table using the synonym as input.

I need to generate for over 400 synonyms, hence searching for a method to retrieve DDL using synonyms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of DDL statement you want to generate.

Comment: DDL of the object(table in my case) which a synonym is pointing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tables:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', table_name)
from user_synonyms
where synonym_name in ...;
```

For other object types as well:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(o.object_type, s.table_name)
from user_synonyms s join user_objects o on (s.table_name = o.object_name)
where s.synonym_name in ...;
```

Comment: any way to do it using Toad for Oracle?

Comment: I've done this using Export DDL option which is available in Toad for Oracle.